# OS X is repeatedly asking for login keychain password

Tags: macos, security, password, keychain

I know this has been asked here several times, but I already checked the other discussions and tried their suggestions, but without success.
Is there anything I can do instead of re-installing the complete system?

**When certain applications want to access the keychain, I am getting asked for the "login" keychain password repeatedly and never-ending, even though I type in the correct password.**

I already tried the following, separate from each other:

- `Keychain Access > Preferences > Reset my default key chain`
- reset the password (new password = old password) of the login keychain
- Deleting the `~/Library/Keychains/XYZ...` folder (as suggested here:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/148437/5924)
- restarted several times

Now I wanted to simply grant access to all applications to certain keychains, but when wanting to save the changes, I have the same as the original issue: I get asked for the login keychain password, which never gets accepted.
I am definitely typing the correct password, I can even lock and unlock the keychain with it without problems. Or even reset the password. It just won't help.
(And in case it matters: the "login" keychain password is the same that I use for my user account.)

Here is the **screencast video**: **https://www.dropbox.com/home/Public?preview=video3.m4v**

[[image]]

(I'm on El Capitan, the Keychain Access is Version 9.0 (55171.20.2))

*Related discussions, but none of them helped:*

- [OSX is repeatedly asking for login keychain password](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/124591/osx-is-repeatedly-asking-for-login-keychain-password/124630)
- [Mac asking for multiple "login" keychain app passwords but won't accept them](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177836/mac-asking-for-multiple-login-keychain-app-passwords-but-wont-accept-them)
- [How to stop my machine asking for multiple passwords when I log in?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/148433/how-to-stop-my-machine-asking-for-multiple-passwords-when-i-log-in)

***===UPDATE===***

I just came across this thread: [Keychain does not show passwords after El Capitan upgrade](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/222157/keychain-does-not-show-passwords-after-el-capitan-upgrade?rq=1)

and indeed, this is also the message I am getting in the /var/log/system.log:

```
SecurityAgent[877]: Ignoring user action since the dialog has received events from an untrusted source
```

but I am already using a real mouse (Magic Mouse) and/or the built-in touchpad of my Mac, so the proposed solution there does not help much:

> So a solution to this problem is to use a physical mouse to interact
>   with the Keychain.

(By the way: I have all recent updates installed that I got auto-notified about via App Store.)

What's also interesting, looking at the system.log: it shows a lot of these lines quite frequentely, without any user interaction and every few seconds:

```
secd[292]:  __SOSCCProcessSyncWithAllPeers_Server_block_invoke sync with all peers failed: Error Domain=com.apple.security.sos.error Code=1032 "peer: UQl/Oz6WIs//dOl3o8fSLDAa2p not found" UserInfo={NSDescription=peer: UQl/Oz6WIs//dOl3o8fSLDAa2p not found}
Mar 21 22:40:04 mln-mbp CloudKeychainProxy[344]:  __39-[UbiqitousKVSProxy doSyncWithAllPeers]_block_invoke_2 <UB--s--C---> syncWithAllPeers (null), rescheduling timer
```

(Now I just removed the keychain from being stored on iCloud and the error in the log stopped.)

Comment: Have you already tried ye ole Repair Permissions routine (Disk Utility's First Aid) and the repair home folder permissions (from the Recovery Partition system)?

Comment: @DictionaricsAnonymous I just ran a First Aid, and I got some errors. Even though the First Aid dialog says "It will then repair the volume if necessary.", the volume still shows the errors if I ran First Aid for again.  http://snag.gy/A9JAJ.jpg About permission repair of home folder: how to access that / I don't seem to have a recovery partition, when looking into the partitions (see screenshot). Would the partition not appear there as well? Is the DiskUtility that I can access via boot & cmd+R different than the DiskUtility I ran First Aid from? (Doing a TimeMachine backup before next steps)

Comment: Nevermind about the partition, I see it via "diskutil list" - http://pastebin.com/XfBViF3B and a forum discussion on El Capitan https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7254480?tstart=0

Comment: Ah, I don't have El Capitan and didn't know it brought some changes … If not everything has changed, you need to boot to the Recovery system (restart +hold down Cmd-R), then launch Disk Utility and let it repair 'Macintosh HD' from there. It should fix that file system corruption. If not, run it again. But my original idea was to repair PERMISSIONS, and this feature was removed from Disk Utility in El Capitan. I suggest you fix that corruption first, then attempt to repair the two permission systems. I'll have to google around to see if that even still applies to El Capitan...

Comment: To reset the home folder folder permissions, boot into the Recovery system, launch the Terminal application (Utilities menu) and type in the command `resetpassword` (in one word). A separate application will launch, in which you select 'Macintosh HD' and then your user name, then click 'Reset' at the bottom of the window.

Comment: @DictionaricsAnonymous I just tried above, but the dialog that comes up after 'resetpassword' did neither show any disk nor any user that I could have selected. Maybe I need to run step 1 as mentioned here https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5275515?tstart=0 first.

Comment: Screenshot: http://snag.gy/OSUt1.jpg

Comment: Doesn't look too good to me.  Have you already tried to repair the whole drive with First Aid, I mean, whilst in the Recovery system? In Disk Utility,  select the whole drive, not just Macintosh HD. Hope you have your important files already copied to safety.

Comment: @DictionaricsAnonymous Yes, I ran that before and strangely, it ran through very fast (other than when I run it in the regular mode) and did not show any errors in the log. Regarding the resetpassword issue, I opened a new question here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/231824/reset-password-app-in-recovery-mode-not-showing-and-disks I do have a time machine backup and other than the keychain issue, I don't have any issues with my Mac so far, which I use as a development machine mainly.

Comment: Good. Oh, El Capitan, what have you done :) If it were my Mac, I'd consider completely reinstalling OS X with repartitioning and reformatting the drive first...

Comment: @DictionaricsAnonymous You're probably right. But indeed, seems to be an El Capian issue, see my update in the OP.

Comment: @DictionaricsAnonymous I meanwhile solved the original problem; I was then also able to see my HD after disabling FileVault, however, the disk repair fails with "The file system verify or repair failed", screenshot: http://snag.gy/webdr.jpg, although I am not experiencing any issues with my Mac. I will just live with this corrupt system until it really breaks. I always have a backup anyway. Thanks for your help on this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just **disabled FileVault** under my `System Settings > Security & Privacy` last night and let the HD decrypt again and voila, now the keychain works fine again.
I had activated it only recently, but had no idea that this would cause such problems and side-effects.

(Other issues with FileVault are probably related, such as [Reset Password app in recovery mode not showing and disks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/231824/reset-password-app-in-recovery-mode-not-showing-and-disks))

Comment: Interesting.  I only started using El Capitan (on a brand new MBP) two days ago, and I haven't seen any issues so far with Keychain Access despite what I've read—but I disabled FileVault when installing the OS.  I wonder if that is why?  (Why I've had no Keychain issues, I mean.)

Answer (score 10):

I had **exactly** the same problem with Lync messenger - request to enter a keychain password, over and over again, even though password was the correct one. Tried numerous suggestions, nothing worked. Until I found this one:

- go to the folder **userid/Library/Keychains**
- look for a key with the file name from the password request window
- delete this file (only this one!)
- try again your app - password is accepted now

Somehow this key was not shown in Keychain Access, like it does not exist. But actual key file was present in keychain folder.

Seems to be some bug in macOS (I am on Sierra) when it can't see key-file, and then another bug - system tries to create a new key-file, but file operation fails (file already exists there). 
I would suggest to the apple devs to add a proper exception handling there, but I am satisfied for now - problem fixed.

Comment: Exact error I had, worked perfectly.

Comment: Re "not shown"; Is it because you have hidden it in KeyChain (menu View)?

Comment: Click "Show Expired Certificates" and "Show Invisible Items".

Answer (score 3):

A boot into Recovery Mode (`Command + R` right after reboot) and `Disk Utility > First Aid` on the main disk solved the problem for me.

Comment: But what's the main cause?